# Elasticsearch returning invalid JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an interesting issue in Elasticsearch. When performing searches it returns invalid json, such that when I try to run, `JSON.parse(response)` it results in a parse error (Node.js).

Here's what the response data looks like:

```
{
    "took":5,
    "timed_out":false,
    "_shards": {
        "total":5,
        "successful":5,
        "failed":0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total":28,
        "max_score": 1.1264253,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "v1",
                "_id":"AUsTvTc0HrKvNpcAkwza",
                "_score": 1.1264253,
                "_source": {
                    "term":"Value"
                },
            },   
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "v1",
                "_id":"BRxvTMggf5NTMnxwzalF",
                "_score": 0.1328153,
                "_source": {
                    "term":"Other Value"
                },
            }  
        ]
   }
}
```

As you'll notice after the `_source` property there is a comma, even though it's the last property in that object.

In order to be able to parse this I have to run the following code:

```
var json = response.replace(/,\s+}/g, '}');
    json = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then it will parse, but this is simply a band-aid. What I can't figure out is, *WHY* is Elasticsearch returning my JSON like that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is an issue similar to [this one](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7626)
Its a known bug and appears when you wrongly index the JSON document.
Fix here would be to remove that document and index it correctly again.

Comment: Seems different. In my response the error exists outside of the source object.

Comment: If that is the case , can you GET that document and examine ?